# Iphone 7 Plus doesn't start up and stuck in loop while charging

Tags: iphone, battery, charging

I have an iPhone 7 plus which has this weird problem.

It doesn't start up with the side button. Doesn't matter for how much long I hold the side button it doesn't turn on. I thought may be the battery has drained out. But while charging(either through charger or laptop), the Apple logo appears for some seconds and then disappears, afterwards this loop of appearance and disappearance continues on. If I unplug the phone then again I am unable to power up the phone using the side button.

This problem has started after trying to update it.

Answer (score 0):

From https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201412:

1. Press and hold both the side button and the volume down button until you see the Apple logo.
2. If your phone doesn't turn on, follow [these steps to check your hardware and charge your phone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201569#slow). You might need to charge for up to an hour.
3. If your phone still doesn't turn on, contact [Apple Support](https://getsupport.apple.com/?caller=kbase).